# Text rendering vs ImageView rendering in android

Tags: android, performance, rendering

I have a map on which I have to put many markers say 300 I can put custom textviews or images as markers , I wanted to know the performance issues of putting 300 images on map to putting 300 textviews . Which one shall I use for best performance and why ?

Comment: try to use clustering

Comment: @SercanOzdemir -- I am already using clustering , I just wanted to know the tradeoffs in using image or a text when you have so many markers